# Problem with colors in newsletter email

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, newsletter

Have a look at this:

[image]

Is anyone else seeing the newsletter like this in their email? This is in Gmail, in Chrome; it looks the same in Safari.

Is this already a known bug?

Comment: Yes. I just checked with Gmail/Chrome and have a similar color issue.

Comment: @freiheit - This is still going on. Any chance of migrating this to Meta.SO, or should I just copypasta this and then close the original?

Comment: Was about to post this myself. I'd upvote if I could.

Answer (score 4):

We have pushed a fix for this, it will be in the next production build. Please confirm it's fixed next time you receive the newsletter. Apparently there was a weird gmail bug that strips the background color for some reason.

Comment: Beautiful! Will report back when the next newsletter goes out.